# flask-websocket emit in thread is broadcasting when it shouldn't

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, flask-socketio

I have the following thread that emits to the websocket that is working, but if I have two browser windows ( or multiple clients connect) they all see the same data being pushed.  In the example code from https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO appears that I shouldn't even need to specify broadcast=False, but I tried it and it still shows up in all connected websocket windows.

```
@socketio.on('job_submit', namespace='/socket')
def job_submit(message):
    emitter('received job')
    # start job and kick off thread to read and emit output of job (setup in redis list)
    job = background_task.delay()
    runme = test_duplicates(message)
    if runme:
        threads[len(threads) + 1] = {'thread': None, 'thread_lock': Lock()}
        global thread
        thread = threads[len(threads)]['thread']
        with threads[len(threads)]['thread_lock']:
            if thread is None:
                thread = socketio.start_background_task(output_puller, job)
        threads[len(threads)]['thread'] = thread
        threads[len(threads)]['thread'].setName(message['data'])


def output_puller(job):
    while job.state != 'SUCCESS' and job.state != 'FAILURE':
        result = r_server.lpop(job.id)
        if result:
            socketio.emit('my_response', {'data': result.decode()}, namespace='/socket', broadcast=False)
            print(result)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My default, socket.io will broadcast to everyone who connects. If you want to broadcast to a specific client, you'll need to grab the session id on connect:

below is a flask example

```
@io.on('connected')
def connected():
    print "%s connected" % (request.namespace.socket.sessid)
    clients.append(request.namespace)
```

And when you want to send.

```
clients[k].emit('message', "Hello at %s" % (datetime.now()))
```

you tell it which client to send to instead of a global emit

Comment: request.namespace is a string for me so I cant use .socket

Comment: see if you have a request.sid.

http://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

check the section under rooms

Comment: I do have request.sid.  I added this to my emit and it is now working correctly.

Comment: for future reference,      socketio.emit('my_response', {'data': result.decode()}, namespace='/socket', room=sid)